# Gcc Error: cc1 not found

Tags: compiling, gcc

I've a system with `gcc 4.2.4` on board, but when I try to compile even a simple hello world I obtain this error:

```
$ gcc helloworld.c
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I've checked and actually cc1 is not present in the system.
Also, I've noticed that some folders required from gcc (e.g., `/usr/lib/gcc/` and `/usr/libexec/gcc`) are missing.

Is there any possibility to restore the installation of gcc without trying to recompile it entirely?

Comment: What OS and version?

Comment: STLinux 2.3 ARM

Answer (score 3):

Being an embedded Linux, [STLinux](http://www.stlinux.com/) isn't going to have all of the tools that you expect from a desktop Linux. At least, they're not all going to be installed by default.

Many embedded Linuxes don't even have compilers "on board". You have to do all development with a [cross-compilation toolchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-compiler).

STLinux isn't quite that pared down. You just have to [install the GNU tools](http://www.stlinux.com/install/getting-started/installing-gnu-tools) for it.

For what it's worth, `cc1` is [the core part of the GNU C compiler](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77779/relationship-between-cc1-and-gcc). The fact that you're missing it but you have `gcc` means you haven't actually got GCC properly installed.